# ¿ como guardar tarjeta con mercado de pago y node js?

Tags: nodejs, mercadopago

Estoy integrando mercado de pago con mi aplicacion en node.js. cuando trato de agregar la tarjeta con los parametros de la documentacion recibo el siguiente error.

```
{ code: '118', description: 'the body must be a Json Object' }
```

Esto sucede a pesar que le estoy enviando un Json Object.

```
const cardData = {
        'token': cardToken,
        'customer_id': customerId,
        'issuer_id': '1',
        'payment_method_id': 'visa'
      }
      const card = await mercadopago.card.create(cardData)
```

Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema ? o que tenga experiencia con mercado de pago porfavor

pdt: al hacer typeof a cardData sale json.

Comment: Hola!, pudiste resolverlo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Justo tuvimos ese problema y se solucionó enviando solamente el token de la tarjeta, la documentación de Mercado Pago está desactualizada, pero en el end point de su API se aprecia mejor. Adjunto la URL de su API.

Usando una peticion `POST` a:

```
/v1/customers/{customer_id}/cards
```

> Almacena de manera segura en nuestro servidores la referencia de la
> tarjeta utilizada por el cliente en el pago para evitar volver a pedir
> todos los datos en futuras transacciones.

https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/developers/es/reference/cards/_customers_customer_id_cards/post